# Terraform count method with modules

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using terraform and provisioning resources with modules.
In some environments I want to create a module, in others not, what is the best way to do so?
Trying with count method:

```
module "module_name" {
  create                   = var.create_module
  source                   = "../../modules/module" 
}
```

inside the module contains of course resources that check whether to create the resource or not :

```
resource "some resource" "main" {
  count = var.create  == true ? 1 : 0
```

since I am using count inside the module I get the following error on ALL the resources in the model (dozens):

```
Because some_resource.main has "count" set, its attributes must
be accessed on specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    some_resource.main[count.index]
```

Is there any way to use count, inside the module or the root and not to refactor the whole code for [count.index] (that who knows might lead to lots of other problems)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variance in attributes based on count.index in terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186380/variance-in-attributes-based-on-count-index-in-terraform)

Answer (score 8):

The error message indicates that you somewhere try to access `some_resource.main.some_attribute` while you need to access (due to the count) `some_resource.main[0].some_attribute`.

However, if the entire module should be created depending on some condition, it is a cleaner approach to remove the `count` from the resources an add it to the module:

```
module "module_name" {
  count                    = var.create_module ? 1 : 0
  source                   = "../../modules/module" 
}
```